# How to call a function in a class?

Tags: python

I try to call a function in a class from my `Main()`

Basically, I try to built an `Employee` class with internal function. In my main, I try to call these function but it doesn't work.

Am I missing something ?

```
class Employee:
    'Common base class for all employees'

    empCount = 0
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        Employee.empCount += 1

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print("Name : ", self.name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary)
    def test(self):
        print("This is a test")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        x = Employee("Maxime", 75000)
        y = Employee("Sacha", 100000)
        x.displayEmployee   # Nothing appear in my console ?
        x.test # Nothing appear in my console ?
```

Why doesn't the `DisplayEmployee()` function print anything in my console?

Comment: `x.displayEmployee()` (mind the parentheses.)

Comment: if you want to call the function, you need to use parenthesis after the function name, e.g. `x.displayEmployee()`

Comment: Your `if __name__ == '__main__'` block is indented and is therefore part of the class. You can't use the class `Employee` at that point because you haven't finished defining it yet. Unindent that block to the same level as `class`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys !

Comment: I don't think indentation is the problem. The OP doesn't mention an error. I think that's a pasting problem. The real issue is almost certainly that they're simply not calling the functions.

Answer (score 1):

You should unident the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block and the call should be `x.displayEmployee()`, note the parens.